# How to see the line numbers on crash with bazel

Tags: c++, debugging, segmentation-fault, bazel

I used gdb before and it was possible to obtain the line numbers where the program crashed with `bt` command, standing for backtrace. It is then very easy to locate where the bug (e.g. segmentation fault) occurs.

I am looking for a similar feature in bazel. I compiled with

```
bazel build -c dbg //...
```

It already gives me a more informative output than `-c opt` but does not show the line numbers.
Is it possible to get the line numbers as well in bazel? I included my stack trace below.

```
*** Aborted at 1619445043 (unix time) try "date -d @1619445043" if you are using GNU date ***
PC: @                0x0 (unknown)
*** SIGSEGV (@0x0) received by PID 3177568 (TID 0x7f325db34880) from PID 0; stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f325dda53c0 (unknown)
    @     0x55d0e0d6e6b2 std::vector<>::operator[]()
    @     0x55d0e0d693f8 _ZZ11MineDCRulesvENKUlRKN9codelearn18GitHubFileRevisionERKN10eventgraph19OriginalTreesChangeERKNS3_18SourceGraphStorageES9_E_clES2_S6_S9_S9_
    @     0x55d0e0d6a096 _ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFvRKN9codelearn18GitHubFileRevisionERKN10eventgraph19OriginalTreesChangeERKNS4_18SourceGraphStorageESA_EZ11MineDCRulesvEUlS3_S7_SA_SA_E_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_dataS3_S7_SA_SA_
    @     0x55d0e0d935cc std::function<>::operator()()
    @     0x55d0e0d81466 _ZZ36TraverseDatalogAnalyzedFilesInternalRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEiibP9StringSetPN4absl5MutexEPKSt8functionIFvRKN9codelearn18GitHubFileRevisionERKN10eventgraph19OriginalTreesChangeERKNSH_18SourceGraphStorageESN_EEbENKUlS6_E_clES6_
    @     0x55d0e0d888a2 _ZNSt17_Function_handlerIFvRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEZ36TraverseDatalogAnalyzedFilesInternalS7_iibP9StringSetPN4absl5MutexEPKSt8functionIFvRKN9codelearn18GitHubFileRevisionERKN10eventgraph19OriginalTreesChangeERKNSJ_18SourceGraphStorageESP_EEbEUlS7_E_E9_M_invokeERKSt9_Any_dataS7_
    @     0x55d0e0dacb93 std::function<>::operator()()
    @     0x55d0e0da90e5 _Z19ForEachFileInternalP16SimpleThreadPoolRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEibRKSt8functionIFvS8_EE.localalias
    @     0x55d0e0da98cc _Z19ForEachFileInternalP16SimpleThreadPoolRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEibRKSt8functionIFvS8_EE.localalias
    @     0x55d0e0da98cc _Z19ForEachFileInternalP16SimpleThreadPoolRKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEibRKSt8functionIFvS8_EE.localalias
    @     0x55d0e0da9b57 ForEachFile()
    @     0x55d0e0d81c79 TraverseDatalogAnalyzedFilesInternal()
    @     0x55d0e0d83271 TraverseDatalogAnalyzedFilesWithMetadata()
    @     0x55d0e0d699f8 MineDCRules()
    @     0x55d0e0d69e3c main
    @     0x7f325db680b3 __libc_start_main
    @     0x55d0e0d6836e _start
    @                0x0 (unknown)
tools/scripts/train.sh: line 94: 3177568 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $DC_MINER $LOGGING --repos_dir $RAWDATA --transform $LANGUAGE --histories_dir $HISTORIES --eval_histories $TEST_HISTORIES --num_parallel_threads $NUM_CPU --out_dir $EMB_DIR --database $DATABASE/$LANGUAGE --ontology_dir $DATABASE/rules
```